# create android action bar menu with Sherlock

Tags: android, android-layout, actionbarsherlock

I want to create android action bar with Sherlock according to bottom picture.

[image: one]

how to put the title bar on center and my lists icon align to be right
although another icon set be left.

Answer (score 0):

ActionbarSherlock is very much outdated. You should use the AppCompat library, for which a ton of documentation exists.